# Error 500 when using ajax in symfony2 project

Tags: jquery, symfony

The ajax feature is on route `http://mysite/playlist-edit/3`

Javascript:

```
    $("#applySort").click(function(){
        var list = $("#sortable").sortable('toArray');

        $.post({
                type: 'POST',
                url: " {{ path('save_sorting', { 'id' : customer.id}) }} ",
                data: { "list" : JSON.stringify(list) },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("success");
                }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Route:

```
save_sorting:
    pattern: /save-sorting/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: SomeApiBundle:Customer:applySorting}
    requirements:
       _method: POST
```

Controller action (empty):

```
private function applySortingAction($id){

}
```

Error:

POST `http://mysite/playlist-edit/%5Bobject%20Object%5D` 500 Internal Server Error

As you can see in the javascript code `http://mysite/playlist-edit/%5Bobject%20Object%5D` is actually not the url in the javascript, it should be `http://mysite/save-sorting/3`.

Jquery seems to call the wrong url.

```
Request-Header
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  PHPSESSID=rkdre4frkoidgo3n1hsi4th7v5
DNT 1
Host    gartenfernsehen
Referer  http://mysite/playlist-edit/3
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest

Response-Header
Connection  close
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Mon, 25 Jun 2012 06:21:07 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.8
```

Any ideas why I get this error? I notices that `http://mysite/playlist-edit/%5Bobject%20Object%5D` is actually wrong but I dont know how this is created.

Comment: There's something with your customer object. It looks likes customer->id is an object... You should have a look at and post your log about this error.

Comment: I hate to ask the obvious, but is your javascript code in a twig template?

Comment: Yes it is in the twig template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not expect this. But I changed **$.post** to **$.ajax** and now the right url is requested.

Answer (score 1):

Your action method in your controller should be named:

```
public function applySortingAction($id){
}
```

`$id` being the `{id}` parameter of your `save_sorting` route

Comment: Thanks for this, but it's actually not the problem, see my edit.